# jQuery function is not working in my MVC Application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my `MVC` application `onclick` function is not working.

```
@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/plugins/toastr/toastr.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var page = 0;
            var type = "Category";

            function Count(param) {
                if (param === 1) {
                    page++;
                }
                else if (param === -1) {
                    if (count === 0) {
                        return;
                    }
                    page--;
                }

            }

            function Search() {
                var query = $("#searchquery").val();

            }

            function ListResult(param) {

                if (param === "Category") {
                    type = param;
                    page = 0;
                    $(".category_type").css({ "color": "green" });
                } else if (param === "Product") {
                    type = param;
                    page = 0;
                    $(".product_type").css({ "color": "green" });
                }

            }
        });
    </script>
}
```

In the Code above, there is a `script` tag of my code, and code below is the html part. I don't understand why it is not working . 
I wrote alert to test if  tag is working. It is working but problem is  `function is not defined`

```
 <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button" onclick="Search()">
                            @Resources.Resource.btn_Search
                        </a> 
 <a class="btn btn-white btn-sm" onclick="Count(1)"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
                <a class="btn btn-white btn-sm" onclick="Count(-1)"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>

  <li><a href="#" onclick="ListResult('Category')" class="category_type type"style="color: green"><i class="fa fa-folder category_type type"style="color: green"></i> @Resources.Resource.Categories</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" onclick="ListResult('Product')"class="product_type type"><i class="fa fa-folder product_type type"></i> @Resources.Resource.Products</a></li>
```

> DaysOffer:193 Uncaught ReferenceError: Search is not defined
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (DaysOffer:193)

How can I resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that your `li` elements need to be inside a `ul` or `ol` - although I assume that's just an issue with how you copy/pasted the question

Answer (score 6):

You've defined the `Search()` function within the `document.ready` handler, so it's not in scope of the `window` as it needs to be when you call the function from an `on*` event attribute. The same is also true of your `Count()` and `ListResult()` functions.

To fix this, either move the function definition to the correct scope (ie. outside `$(document).ready()`), or use an unobtrusive event handler to attach the events in your JS code. The latter is by far the better approach.

Answer (score 4):

Move your functions outside `document.ready()`. There's no need for them to be there, because they wouldn't execute immediately anyway. You're having a scoping problem - your inline event handlers can't see the functions inside document.ready because it expects them to be in the global window context, and they're not.

Or, use unobtrusive event handlers instead of inline ones in your HTML, which 
will generally make your code clearer and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Define function outside ready function:

```js
var page = 0;
var type = "Category";

function Count(param) {
  if (param === 1) {
    page++;
  } else if (param === -1) {
    if (count === 0) {
      return;
    }
    page--;
  }

}

function Search() {
   alert("Search function triggered")
  var query = $("#searchquery").val();

}

function ListResult(param) {

  if (param === "Category") {
    type = param;
    page = 0;
    $(".category_type").css({
      "color": "green"
    });
  } else if (param === "Product") {
    type = param;
    page = 0;
    $(".product_type").css({
      "color": "green"
    });
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button" onclick="Search()">
                            @Resources.Resource.btn_Search
                        </a>
<a class="btn btn-white btn-sm" onclick="Count(1)"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
<a class="btn btn-white btn-sm" onclick="Count(-1)"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>

<li><a href="#" onclick="ListResult('Category')" class="category_type type" style="color: green"><i class="fa fa-folder category_type type"style="color: green"></i> @Resources.Resource.Categories</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="ListResult('Product')" class="product_type type"><i class="fa fa-folder product_type type"></i> @Resources.Resource.Products</a></li>
```